# Is there another way to observe for changes to a sub property of an object in Google Polymer 1.0?

Tags: routes, polymer

I've tried the deep path observation examples on the Google Polymer site but it does not work for my case. The sub-property I want to observe is an array that gets changed when I go to a different hash url. The problem is I'm using a library that handles that change so it doesn't use polymer's "push, pop, shift and splice" and without that, Polymer won't recognize the array mutation. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should add some code example, thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had what I think is a similar problem when trying to be notified of changes to an array in a computed property.

In my case I wanted to know when it's children were modified so that I could recompute something else with the changed children.  Here's a snippet of working code from a polymer element:

```
properties: {
    choices: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true,
        value: []
    },
    choicesTransposed: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true,
        computed: '_transposeChoices(choices.*)'
    }
},

_transposeChoices: function(change) {
    var choices = change.base;
    // do something with choices
}
```

Initially I had `_transposeChoices(choices)` but this was never called when `choices` children were modified.  Changing that to `_transposeChoices(choices.*)` and then using `change.base` in the computing function is what got things working for me.

Comment: This would definitely work if I could bind the array in question but how would I do that? I've done it using the two way data binding in the html but that raises some other issues unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js) to observe you object, and interact with Polymer by [custom event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html).